# Bulk Insert with Mariasql Node js

Tags: node.js, mariasql

I want to perform bulk insert operation using Mariasql Node Js module, but it is showing error "**Column count dosen't match value count at Row 1**"

Below is my code :

```
var queryObj= [["Test1","false"],["Test2","true"]]
mariaDb.query("INSERT INTO apps (app_name,status) values (app_name=?,status=?)",queryObj,{useArray:true},mycallback)
```

Database scheme is also having two columns with varchar(10)

Could anyone please help what I am doing wrong